# Dictionary keys with non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: vimscript

Given a dictionary:

```
let g:dict = {
    \ 'FOO/BAR': 'BAZ',
    \ 'FIZZ': 'BUZZ'
}
```

Vim is fine with this:

```
:echo g:dict.FIZZ
```

But chokes on this:

```
:echo g:dict.FOO/BAR

E716: Key not present in Dictionary: HCL/HCL_0127
E15: Invalid expression: g:dict.FOO/BAR
```

I've also tried escaping the forward slash as `\/`, which doesn't work. However, it has no problem with `g:dict['FOO/BAR']`.

Is there any way to access these entries using the dot syntax? Are there other characters I have to watch out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the dot form in your case because your key has something other than a letter, number, underscore:

`:help dict`

> Accessing entries
>
> The normal way to access an entry is by putting the key in square
>   brackets:
>
> `:let val = mydict["one"]`
>   `:let mydict["four"] = 4`
>
> You can add new entries to an existing Dictionary this way, unlike
>   Lists.
>
> For keys that consist entirely of *letters, digits and underscore* the following
>   form can be used |expr-entry|:
>
> `:let val = mydict.one`
>   `:let mydict.four = 4`